# Meteor Objects Are Undefined Why?

Tags: meteor

Here is my code using Papa Parse (CSV Parser Library)

```
            Papa.parse(theFile.target.result, {
                header: true,
                step: function(row) {
                    Meteor.call('file-upload', row.data); 
                }
```

row.data is a object looks like:

```
[
    {
        "Column 1": "foo",
        "Column 2": "bar"
    },
    {
        "Column 1": "abc",
        "Column 2": "def"
    }
]
```

I'm having difficulty finding the object values using Meteor method so I can add it to my collection the following is `rowData.Desc rowData.Title` are undefined... Echoing `row.data` to browser console shows everything fine. Any ideas whats wrong?

```
Meteor.methods({
    'file-upload': function(rowData) {
        Products.insert({
            Title: rowData.Title,
            Desc: rowData.Desc
        })
    }

});
```

Comment: Does `row.data` have `row.data.Title` and `rowD.data.Desc` properties defined?  Because that is what the `file-upload` method you show uses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where are you getting "rowData.Title" from? rowData appears to be an array, not an object. And the property title does not even exist in the nested objects.

But I think I know what you're trying to do.

It looks like you either just need to store the data by iterating over the array, or render it differently in your template.

If each one of those object literals in your array is a product, then what you probably want to do is iterate over that array and insert the data that way:

```
Meteor.methods({
    'file-upload': function(rowData) {
        _.each( rowData, function(data) {
            Products.insert({
                Title: rowData["Column 1"],
                Desc: rowData["Column 2"]
            })
        });
     }
});
```

---

Some additional things you could do to trouble shoot:

First, make sure your method is receiving the data that it needs on the server by logging it to the terminal:

```
Meteor.methods({
    'file-upload': function(rowData) {
        console.log('rowData: ', rowData);
        ....
```

Make sure the shows up in the terminal.

If your data is data is there, and you don't see in errors in the terminal, then open a new tab in the terminal and run meteor's mongo command to open the mongo shell.

```
$ meteor mongo
```

Next, list all the collections and find that collection—most likely products

```
> show collections
```

And list the documents for that collection to make sure the data is being stored:

```
> db.products.find().pretty()
```